# How to check if value already exists?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small app that users can use to search for a movie, and then add it to their watchlist. Currently it is possible to add 1 movie multple times for the same user. Which ofcourse isn't expected behaviour.

My solution would be to find the unique id of the movie that's being added and crosscheck that with my `movies_users` data. If the `movie_id` value exists, do this, else do this.

At the moment I do have the unique movie id of the movie that's being added,

```
$scope.movieListID = response;
console.log ($scope.movieListID.id)
```

Which gets ouputted like a string, like so,

```
314365
```

And I got the movie records from the current user,

```
$scope.moviesCheck = response.data;
console.log ($scope.moviesCheck)
```

Which looks like this,

```
[{"id":2,"title":"Black Panther", "movie_id":"284054"}]
```

So what would be a good way to check if the result from `$scope.movieListID.id` already exists in the `$scope.moviesCheck` data?

*** update ***

Trying a suggestion below does not give the expected result.

```
var exists = function (id) {
  $scope.moviesCheck.forEach(function (movie) {
    console.log (movie.movie_id)
    console.log (id)
    if (movie.movie_id === id)
      console.log ('duplicate')
    else
      console.log ('not duplicate')

  });
}

exists($scope.movieListID.id);
```

The console.log output from this is,

```
312221
312221
not duplicate
```

Which clearly are duplicate results.

Comment: Don't use triple equal. Until the values are same and the type are same, the result won't be true. For example, 1=="1" will yield true. But 1==="1" will not yield true. Check this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function in your controller to check if the movie exists in the list

```
var exists = function (id) {
    $scope.moviesCheck.forEach(function (movie) {
        if (movie.id === id)
            return true;
    });

    return false;
}

// and call it
exists($scope.movieListID.id); // true or false
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Going to try it out in a minute, quick question though. Do you think a forEach is going to impact the browser speed much? I don't expect many movie results though.

Comment: Instead of foreach go with native for. The for loop consistently came out over 40 times faster than the foreach.

Comment: @CaptainMat I've tried your suggestion but it's not working as expected. I've put the example and result in my question.

Comment: is it a string and a number ? if yes, try with just == instead of ===

Comment: Yea seems to be something like that.

Comment: @CaptainMat How would you bind one action to the result of the check? So if the movie does not exists, do this, else do that. Since you are using a forEach.

Answer (score -1):

From your question I've understood that, based on the object exists using id in the array of object, you have to do different action.

> You can use $filter for this. Inject the filter for your controller and assign it to the scope. So this will be available whenever you want in this controller.

```
$scope.cFilter('filter')($scope.movies, {movie_id:$scope.existingMovie.movie_id}, true);
```

> **$sope.movies** - is the list of movies passed to the filter. You can
>   send any list based on your need.
>
> **{movie_id:$scope.existingMovie.movie_id}** - This one is the object
>   which one we need to find. This can be based on your need. Since we
>   are searching **movie_id**, we need to send the object with property
>   and value. {movie_id:$scope.existingMovie.movie_id}, Here movie_id is
>   the property and followed by the value with the colon.
>
> **true**: This indicates that, to search exact matched values. By default
>   this is false. If this is set to false, then if we want to search 54
>   in the movie id, this will returns the objects whichever contains 54
>   as part of the value.

app.controller('controller', ['$filter',function($filter){
                 $scope.cFilter= $filter;

```
           $scope.Exists=function(){
 $scope.movies=[{"id":2,"title":"Black Panther", "movie_id":"284054"},{"id":3,"title":"Black Panther", "movie_id":"32343"},{"id":4,"title":"Black Panther", "movie_id":"98863"}]

$scope.existingMovie={"id":3,"title":"Black Panther", "movie_id":"32343"};

var _obj=$scope.cFilter('filter')($scope.movies, {movie_id:$scope.existingMovie.movie_id}, true);
                if(_obj && _obj[0])
                {
                  Console.log('object exists')
                }
               else
               {
                 Console.log('Object is not found')
               }
            }

        }])
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the logic behind this code. You use filter, and id as a value, but I can't see what you are filtering. You have _obj as a example variable?

Comment: I've written in generalized format. Now you can see, I've modified the code. Now $scope.movies is the collection of movie.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% if this is a good way to do this, but for me it works and I think it's pretty low on performance,

```
movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
  $scope.moviesCheck = response.data;

  var arr = $scope.moviesCheck
  function myIndexOf(o) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i].movie_id == o.exisitingMovie_id) {
              return i;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  }
  var checkDuplicate = (myIndexOf({exisitingMovie_id:movie.id}));

  if (checkDuplicate == -1) {
```

Comment: This also looks good. Every high level codes  implementing this internally. But if you are going to write again and again with this same method, then your code size will increase. No much different compare to other. If you want to use less code, use $filter from angular native.

Answer (score -1):

Many Thanks Jeeva Jsb. This got me on the right track, however I thought I would clarify with a practical example that seems to work as expected.

So I have a function called getData which get the AJAX array but we need to check if the record exist before added to scope (else we get duplicates)

```
                    if (d.data.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < d.data.length; i++) {

                        var doesExist = $filter('filter')($scope.notifications, {NotifId:d.data[i].NotifId}, true);

                        if (doesExist.length == 0){
                            $scope.notifications.push(d.data[i]);
                        }                         
                    }
                }
```

This should look familier...

when we are iterating through the returned AJAX object we need to check the ID of the (in my case notificiation)

```
var doesExist = $filter('filter')($scope.notifications, {NotifId:d.data[i].NotifId}, true);
```

This line creates a new array by filtering the existing array in scope ($scope.notifications)  and passing in the same value from you interation.

If the value exists the object will be copied to the new array called doesExist.

A simple check of length will determine if the record needs to be written.

I hope this helps someone.